# Relying on MySQL features vs my script

Tags: mysql

I've always relied on my PHP programming for most processes which I need to do, that I know can be done via a MySQL query or feature. For example:

I know that MySQL has a FOREIGN KEY feature that helps maintain data integrity but I don't rely on MySQL. I might as well make my scripts do this as it is more flexible; I'm basically using MySQL as STORAGE and my SCRIPTS as the processor.

I would like to keep things that way, put most of the load on my coding. I make sure that my scripts are robust to check for conflicts, orphaned rows, etc every time it makes changes and I even have a SYSTEM CHECK routine that runs through all these data verification processes so I really try to do everything on script side as long as it doesn't impact the whole thing's performance significantly (since I know MySQL can do things faster internally I mean I do use MySQL COUNT() functions of course).

Of course any direct changes done to the tables will not trigger routines in my script. but that's a different story. I'm pretty comfortable with doing this and I plan to keep doing this until I am convinced otherwise.

The only thing that I really have an issue with right now is, checking for duplicates.

My current routine is basically inserting products with serial numbers. I need to make sure that there are no duplicate serial numbers entered into the database.

I can simply rely on MySQL UNIQUE constraint to make sure of this or I can do it script side and this is what I did.

This product routine is a BATCH routine  where anything from 1 to 500 products will be entered into the database at one call to the script.

Obviously I check for both duplicate entries in the data submitted as well as the data in the database. Here's a chunk of my routine

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $qty; $i++) {
    //
    $serial = $serials_array[$i - 1]; // -1 coz arrays start at zero

    //check duplicates in submitted data ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    if($serial_check[$serial] == 1) { // duplicate found!
            exit("stat=err&statMsg=Duplicate serial found in your entry! ($serial)");
    }else{
        $serial_check[$serial] = 1;
    }


    //check duplicates in database
    if(db_checkRow("inventory_stocks", "WHERE serial='$serial'"))exit("stat=err&statMsg=Serial Number is already used. ($serial)");
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

}
```

OK so basically it's:

1) Check submitted data for duplicates via creating an array that I can check against each serial number submitted  - THIS IS no problem and really fast with PHP even up to 1000 records.

2) But, to check the database for duplicates, I have to call a function I made (db_checkRow) w/c basically issues a SELECT statement on EACH serial submitted and see if there's a hit/duplicate.

So, basically, 500 SELECT statements to check for duplicates vs just the MySQL unique constraint feature.

Does it really matter much??

Another reason I design my software like this is because at least if I need to deploy my stuff on a different database I don't rely too much on database features, hence I can easily port my application with very little tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong. You're very, dangerously wrong.

The database has been designed for a specific function. You will *never* beat MySQL at enforcing a unique constraint. The database has been designed to do explicitly that as quickly as possible. It is *impossible* that you can do it quicker or more efficiently in PHP as you still need to access the database to determine whether the data you're inserting would be a duplicate.

This is easily demonstrated by the fact that you have *500* select statements to enforce a single unique constraint. As your table grows this will get even more ridiculous. What happens when your table hits 2,000 rows? What if you have a new table with a million rows?

Use the database features that have been designed explicitly to make your life easy.

You're also assuming that the only way the database will be accessed is through the application. This is an extremely dangerous assumption that is almost certain to be incorrect as time progresses.

Please read [this programmers question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/never-do-in-code-what-you-can-get-the-sql-server-to-do-well-for-you-is-this), which seems like it's been written just for you. Simply put, *“Never do in code what you can get the SQL server to do well for you”*. I cannot emphasise this enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your logical, yet scary, input haha.

I do appreciate your angle.. and I guess i see your point..

i guess i just couldnt get my head to relying on 2 processes to do logic for me, like some data verification done on php side and some on SQL side.. i wanted to stay organized and make all logic routines independent of the database/storage engine... i've found myself in situations where i needed to run it on a different database, w/c required massive changes to my php just to maintain what i normally relied on MYSQL.. dont even get me started wen i had to use XML :(

Answer (score 3):

It's almost guaranteed that MySQL will be faster at checking duplicates. Unless you are running your PHP on some uber-machine and the MySQL is running on an old wristwatch the index checking will be faster and better optimized than anything you can do via PHP.

Not to mention that your process is fine until someone else (or some other app) starts writing to the db. You can save yourself having to write the duplicate checking code in the first place - and again in the next app - and so on.

Comment: hmmm.. okok. ill try to change my "thinking" w/ regards to this... tnx much!